# Animating a rectangle to go left for a set amount of time and back and another rectangle to go up and down

Tags: c#, winforms

The problem that I have is that I can't get my animation to work. All I need the program to do is on a button click animate a rectangle to go left up to a point then go back. I used Double animation class but that doesn't want to work

I've already tried using the Double Animation class but that didn't work and crashed my program each time. Its running on visual studio and its a simple program that isn't designed to do much.

```
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new 
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);          
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics;
        formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200));
        System.Drawing.Rectangle rec = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(40, 40, 40, 40);

        myBrush.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();

        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.To = 50;
        da.From = 500;
        da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

The expected result is that the rectangle goes from left to right, reach a certain point, then go right to left . Ideally I want to introduce threads in this program and thought that it would be good to add it here.

Comment: Is this WinForms?  If so, just use a timer.  The DoubleAnimation class was not designed for WinForms.  If it's a temporary graphic, CreateGraphics can work, but usually the advice around here is to just use the graphic from the Paint event of the container that's doing the drawing.

Comment: Yes it is a windows form project. It is not a temporary graphics as it needs to stay there for the duration of the project. How would i be able to use timers?